# Show Tabs with button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I got a `TabBarController` with two Views in my project. Now I want to set a `FirstViewController` with two buttons as `Initial View Controller` when the app launches. The first button should show the `FirstView` in the `TabBarController` and the second button the second one. When one of the two buttons is pressed the `FirstViewController` should disappear and it should only be possible to navigate between the two Views with the Tabs in `TabBarViewController`.

[image: picture of the project]

Comment: You mean tab, not tap.

Comment: Y u are using TabBarController  for the above requirement ?.

Comment: what is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some minor edit, and tested the code I wrote and it works. Control drag from firstButton over to the TabBarController and select Kind as "Show". Then do the same with secondButton.
In your view with the two buttons, I call it First:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class First: UIViewController {

    var firstWasClicked = false
    @IBAction func firstButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        firstWasClicked = true
    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        firstWasClicked = false
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! TabBarController
        controller.firstSelected = firstWasClicked
    }
}
```

then in your TabBarController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var firstSelected = true
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if(firstSelected) {
            self.selectedIndex = 0
        }
        else {
            self.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: could you please paste in your project, you tried that in.

Comment: i get this error override func: "ViewController.swift:23:19: Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: which version of xcode and swift are you using? here is the code: https://github.com/Bjorninn1/TabbedApp

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func didTapFirst(button: UIButton) {
    showViewControllerAt(index: 0)
}

@IBAction func didTapSecond(button: UIButton) {
    showViewControllerAt(index: 1)
}

func showViewControllerAt(index: NSInteger) {
    let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = index
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tabBarController
}
}
```

**Don't forget to set the `Storyboard ID` of your `UITabBarController`.**